# Unix Bash- How to print word count immediately after file name without line break

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, formatting

I am trying to print filenames in my directory with line/word counts all on one line. The way my output is now:

foo.txt

500

bar.txt

210

...
What it should be:

foo.txt 500

bar.txt 210
...

What I am expecting the answer to look like:
wc -l | awk {something}

Comment: If you want to reorder the output from `wc`, try e.g. `wc -l * | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'` but there's a reason it prints the count first; that way, the output is completely unambiguous for even pretty pathological file names.

Comment: Why not just s.t. with `wc -l | tr "\n" " "`? awk seems a little overkill for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple but flawed way to do it:

```
wc -l *.txt | awk '$2 != "total" { print $2, $1 }'
```

However, if you have spaces in the filename, then the above will print the those filenames cut off at the first space. Also, the check for the line with the total is also weak, and breaks spectacularly for a file called "total disaster.txt" (thanks [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) for the shrewd criticism).

Here's a much safer, but a bit longer solution:

```
wc -l *.txt | awk '{ count = $1; sub("^ *[0-9]+ ", ""); if ($0 != "total") print count, $0 }'
```

Comment: That seemed to do it (I copied the echo.....part because your loop is a bit off)!  Thanks.  I just wasn't sure of the $ before the (wc -l....)

Comment: @janos: if the file's name is `a file.txt`, what is the value of `$2` in awk? What about `total disaster.txt`?

Comment: @rici all good points. Anything else I missed in the latest update?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple loop, and awk:

for i in *.txt
do
  awk 'END {printf "%s %d\n", FILENAME, NR}' $i
done

or, you could use wc -l like this:

wc -l *.txt | awk '$2 != "total" {printf "%s %d\n", $2, $1}'

Answer (score -1):

```
 wc -l *.txt |  awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Does the work for the sample input provided in your question?

> Some user is worried about unnecessary space characters in file name

The following should work for you:

```
for i in *.txt; do echo ${i##*/} `wc -l "$i" | awk '{print $1}'`; done
```

Comment: See my question in @janos's answer.